# Pandas: Finding average values of dataframe by hour & month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, mean

Assume I have a df:

```
timestamp             value1     value2
01-01-2010 00:00:00       10          5
30-01-2019 00:00:00        5          1
01-02-2015 12:00:00        1          0
25-02-2007 05:00:00       10         10
01-02-2015 05:00:00       10          1
```

I would like to plot a time series graph based on mean value of columns 'value1' & 'value2' based only on hour & month of the dataset. Desired df & graph may look something like this:

```
hour-month     value1   value2
00-01             7.5        3
05-02              10      5.5
12-02               1        0
```

[image: Time series chart]

I'm new to Python; please advise

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then aggregate `mean` with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert datetimes to `HH-mm` strings and last plot by [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H-%m')).mean()

print (df1)
           value1  value2
timestamp                
00-01         7.5     3.0
05-02        10.0     5.5
12-02         1.0     0.0

df1.plot()
```

EDIT:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2020, day=1))).mean()

print (df1)
                     value1  value2
timestamp                          
2020-01-01 00:00:00     7.5     3.0
2020-02-01 05:00:00    10.0     5.5
2020-02-01 12:00:00     1.0     0.0

df2 = df1.rename_axis('col', axis=1).stack().reset_index(name='vals')
print (df2)
            timestamp     col  vals
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00  value1   7.5
1 2020-01-01 00:00:00  value2   3.0
2 2020-02-01 05:00:00  value1  10.0
3 2020-02-01 05:00:00  value2   5.5
4 2020-02-01 12:00:00  value1   1.0
5 2020-02-01 12:00:00  value2   0.0
```

---

```
import plotly.express as px

#https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/
fig = px.line(df2, x="timestamp", y="vals", color='col')
#https://plotly.com/python/time-series/
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="timestamp",
    tickformat="%H\n%m")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way I can plot this on plotly graphs tho?

Comment: I have tried using your method, however the x-axis of plotly is converted to month & year values. Is there anyway to maintain the hour & month values?

Comment: @AgnesLee - In my data are hours and month, so what was omitted or changed in my code for plot year?

Comment: I used the exact codes as yours: df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H-%m')).mean(); choosing hours & month. However in both the axis & data in tooltip, timestamp was changed to month & year instead, ranging from year 2000 - 2012

Comment: @AgnesLee - Do you plot `df1` ? Or `df` ?

Comment: @AgnesLee - hmmm, it means `plotly` convert `HH:MM` to years

Comment: @AgnesLee - One trick is replace all years and days to some default value and then use custom ticknames, answer is edited.